# net::ERR_FAILED when uploading image to S3 in NUXT

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3, nuxt.js

I am trying to upload images to AWS S3 in my NUXTJS app. I get the error below and I don't know why I am getting it.

```
aws-s3.js?e848:1 POST https://lookaam.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ net::ERR_FAILED
```

Here is what I have done so far, the read files ready the files selected on the browser and saves to AWS.

The second function below is responsible for uploading to AWS

```
        readFiles(file) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file)
            reader.onload = () => {
                const uploading = this.uploading
                const result = reader.result
                uploading.push(result)
                this.uploading = uploading
                
                // convert files, upload to aws, send to backend
                this.saveToAWS(file, result)
            }
        },
        async saveToAWS(file, result) {

            const config = {
                bucketName: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
                dirName: 'photos', /* optional */
                region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
                accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ID,
                secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
                // s3Url: process.env.AWS_URL,
            }

            const S3Client = new S3(config)
            S3Client
            .uploadFile(file, this.getRandomName(10))
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        },
```

and below is my bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyNUMBERHERE",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt162LASTDIGITS",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

in my CORS

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://lookaam.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

apart from what i get in my console, below is what I get in my network tab
[image: lookaam.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com]

Comment: What do you have in your network tab?

Comment: @kissu i updated the question and included the network tab down below

Comment: What is the actual error response there?

Comment: @kissu actually, I was just able to find the solution, apparently, I got the region wrong. AWS shows too many regions and it got me confused. everything works so far.

Comment: @kissu thanks so far, you have answered or guided me so far with the questions I have been posting on this platform, and I have just been able to kinda complete the startup website I am building for myself. incase you want to check it out, it's at [lookaam.com](https://lookaam.com)  I should be pushing the final update by tomorrow